# Using Sencha's ExtJS MVC with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, extjs4, extjs, extjs-mvc

I wanted to ask if anyone has tried using combination of Sencha's ExtJS 4 (using MVC approach) with ASP.NET MVC (using view models)?

I have existing ASP.NET MVC 3 app that uses view models and my question is how would this "fit" into Sencha's MVC approach...Would ASP.NET MVC "view model" become ExtJS "model" and then I would define yet another "view model" for ExtJS....Seems a lot of "translating"...

What would be the best approach?

And yes, I am aware of projects that integrate ASP.NET MVC with ExtJS using Ext.Direct, but my question is strictly relating to MVC paradigm on "both" sides (ASP.NET and Sencha ExtJS)

Thanks
Z...

Comment: Not related to your question, but maybe you should check out [Dextop](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase/).

Comment: @Marko Interesting...But, at first glance, it seems more suitable for "regular" ASP.NET (vs. ASP.NET MVC)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I've not done this with ExtJS, I really don't think there's any conflict.  I'm assuming a lot here, I know, but if ExtJS works with JSON and you've got ASP.NET MVC actions that emit JSON, it's really more of a philosophic difference than a technical one.

One difference from a normal MVC app would be that your ASP.NET MVC app might not have any views, since the views would be handled entirely by ExtJS.

From the server side, ASP.NET MVC really doesn't care - it's getting a request that gets mapped to a controller and action, processing the request and returning some result.  Whether that result is HTML, JSON, XML or whatever, ASP.NET doesn't care at all.

Comment: I agree with you that ASP.NET MVC app will not have *its own* views (the ExtJS will), but ASP.NET MVC app will return a "view model" for ExtJS to use. What I am having difficulty understanding is what to do with/how to map that "view model" into ExtJS app that also uses MVC approach...

Comment: The term "view model" is actually rather foreign to MVC, and is likely to get you confused with the MVVM pattern.  To your question, the ASP.NET MVC app's JsonResult actions would need to return JSON objects that match the structure defined in ExtJS.  However, that doesn't necessarily mean that they have to match the ASP.NET MVC models - you can construct the data however you want in your action.  So you'd define a model in ExtJS and an action in ASP.NET MVC that emitted data that matched that model.  However you chose to structure it in an ASP.NET "model" is really up to you.

Comment: I am familiar with both MVC and MVVM patterns...And there are a lot of ASP.NET MVC applications that use "view models" in addition to regular, domain models. But as you said, on ASP.NET MVC end the action would have to return JsonResult that will be representative of a "model" in ExtJs...

Answer (score 1):

Our approach currently is a what could be described as MVCCM or MVC-CM. 
In ExtJs you have the view as panels and boxes etc, a store with a model makes a model and you need some logic to make these components work together which would be the controller.

This ExtJs frontend is situated in a MVC3 project and exposes controller methods that typically returns Json data which it gets from the model back end which is typically made up of entities.

There is no programmatic link between the entities on the server side and the models defined in the stores client side. One could generated the stores from entities, but we have not looked into this yet.

The view in the Microsoft MVC3 framework is just a page that returns some div tags which ExtJS can render stuff into.